# Настройка приоритета трафика в роутере

Tags: роутер

Каким способом можно настроить роутер, чтобы трафик скажем с локальной машины 192.168.1.2 обладал наивысшим приоритетом, чтобы передаваемые пакеты ставились первыми в очередь!? Если другие компы в локалке качают что то через торрент, то комп 192.168.1.2 в момент работы с Интернет этого вообще не должен замечать (в плане скорости основного канала)

Comment: Роутер какой? Какая прошивка?

Comment: вызывайте телепатов!

Comment: Да всё равно какой, вопрос при помощи каких технологий? (пусть роутером будет D-Link DIR 320 )

Comment: пробовали изучать инструкцию по настройке роутера?

Comment: вообще на многих есть костыли qos его и нужно крутить

Comment: Обычно в инструкциях не рассказывается подробно о таких настройках!QoS будет работать только если его поддерживает провайдер!?Где подробней почитать по настройку QoS? Может кто нибудь с этим сталкивался? Помойму вопрос актуальный, разве нет!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так на память не помню что бы там были такие фитчи. Есть прошивки ddwrt openwrt там точно есть.

Answer (score 1):

однозначно через QоS (качество обслуживания) - только надо курить инструкцию на этот предмет Вашего рутера, т.к. у каждого свои особенности...
Насколько знаю, не все рутеры осуществляют поддержку QoS в полном объеме.